# Does swift have a protocol similar to CustomStringConvertible for verbose, multi-line printing?

Tags: swift

In Swift 2.2 the supplied protocol `CustomStringConvertible` provides for a computed property that returns a string representation.  Typically this it intended for short, single line string representations of simple data types.

Is there a similar protocol, or convention or facility for giving classes more verbose, multi-line descriptive string representations?

Comment: Nope and i don't see any problems in building your own.

Comment: Oh right :) See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`CustomDebugStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CustomDebugStringConvertible_Protocol/index.html)

> This textual representation is used when values are written to an output stream by `debugPrint`, and is typically more verbose than the text provided by a `CustomStringConvertible`'s description property.